# How to select dataframe rows according to multi-(other column)-condition on columnar groups?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, conditional-statements

Copy the following dataframe to your clipboard:

```
  textId   score              textInfo
0  name1     1.0            text_stuff
1  name1     2.0  different_text_stuff
2  name1     2.0            text_stuff
3  name2     1.0  different_text_stuff
4  name2     1.3  different_text_stuff
5  name2     2.0  still_different_text
6  name2     1.0              yoko ono
7  name2     3.0     I lika da Gweneth
8  name3     1.0     Always a tradeoff
9  name3     3.0                What?!
```

Now use

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_clipboard(sep='\s\s+')
```

to load it into your environment. How does one slice this dataframe such that **all** the rows of a particular `textId` are returned if the `score` group of that `textId` includes at least one `score` that equals 1.0, 2.0 and 3.0? Here, the desired operation's result would exclude `textId` rows *name1* since its `score` group is missing a 3.0 and exclude *name3* since its `score` group is missing a 2.0:

```
  textId   score              textInfo
0  name2     1.0  different_text_stuff
1  name2     1.3  different_text_stuff
2  name2     2.0  still_different_text
3  name2     1.0              yoko ono
4  name2     3.0     I lika da Gweneth
```

### Attempts

1. `df[df.textId == "textIdRowName" & df.score == 1.0 & df.score == 2.0
   & & df.score == 3.0]` isn't right since the condition isn't acting
   on the `textId` group but only individual rows. If this could be
   rewritten to match against `textId` groups then it could be placed
   in a for loop and fed the unique *textIdRowName*'s. Such a function
   would collect the names of the `textId` in a series (say
   `textIdThatMatchScore123`) that could then be used to slice the original df
   like `df[df.textId.isin(textIdThatMatchScore123)]`.
2. Failing at `groupby`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one solution - `groupby` textId, then keep only those groups where the unique values of score is a superset (`>=`) of `[1.0, 2.0, 3.0]`.

```
In [58]: df.groupby('textId').filter(lambda x: set(x['score']) >= set([1.,2.,3.]))
Out[58]: 
  textId  score              textInfo
3  name2    1.0  different_text_stuff
4  name2    1.3  different_text_stuff
5  name2    2.0  still_different_text
6  name2    1.0              yoko ono
7  name2    3.0     I lika da Gweneth
```